# Adding strings from a textbox to a listbox with only return keyboard button

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, listbox

I've made up a wpf gui with a textbox and a listbox and a button. Clicking the button transfer the text from textbox to listbox. I want to make possible that if I press Enter (return, or whatever you want to call it) it gets sent to listbox exactl like the button does. How to do that?

here's the code of the button

```
listBox1.Items.Add(BoxListaA.Text);
            BoxListaA.Text = "";
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the IsDefault property on your Button to True.

[Button.IsDefault on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx): "Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a Button is the default button. A user invokes the default button by pressing the ENTER key."

Comment: And now imagine there's another button in the same window that should be invoked when the user hits ENTER while another textbox in that window is focused ;)

Comment: @Tobias: I will imagine that if the user asks that question... :)

Comment: @Tobias handle the key down event on the textbox or have update onpropertychanged and do it in the set